# Wp_insert_post: insert a post with wp_insert_post if the id doesn`t exist in post_type: peliculas

Tags: wordpress

I need help please.
I want to insert a post with this args:

```
$new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $sinopsis,
        'import_id'     =>  $id,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'peliculas'
);
```

but first I have to search in database if the import_id that I'm setting doesn't exist, if the Id exist I have to update a custom field status with 0 and if the id doesn't exist I have to insert the post:

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='peliculas' AND ID = '" . $id . "'";
$db=$wpdb->get_var($query);

$content = get_posts($db);
if ($content){
    update_post_meta( $content, 'status',0,1);
} else{
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $sinopsis,
        'import_id'     =>  $id,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'peliculas'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'titulo', $pelicula->TituloOriginal);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'director', $pelicula->Director);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'actores', $pelicula->Actores);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'genero', $pelicula->Genero);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'clasificacion', $pelicula->Clasificacion);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'duracion', $pelicula->Duracion);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'status', 1);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'imagen', $pelicula->Cartel);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues here:

1. `get_posts` returns an array of posts, but you're treating it like it returns a post ID when you try to update the meta field: `update_post_meta( $content, 'status',0,1);`
2. If you already know the post ID you don't need to manually query the database to check if it exists, just call `get_post($id)`.

--

```
$post = get_post($id);
if ($post && $post->post_type == 'peliculas') {
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'status', 0, 1);
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question.
The thing is: I already know the post ID, but as an imported id, can be repeated in other post types, is why I want to find that $ id in the post type movies only, for example, in the post type restaurants there is a post with id 8748, and import $id has an id equal, if I'm looking the import $id in every post, the post I want to save with the $id equal to the restaurant, it will not save because there is already a post with that id.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @DanielaMondragon In that case you would just need to add additional checks after you fetch the post. Once you have a post object and you verify that it is not null you can check the post type or any other attributes. I updated my answer to check the post type.